# MTA to MTA smtp authentication

Tags: smtp, sendmail, linux, email

How can i setup MTA to MTA smtp authentication.
Scenario: I've an email server which is acting as both incoming/outgoing server with smtp authentication. I want to setup a separate smtp server which would authenticate users for other server.

I want to set up a SECOND smtp server that will be used by users of the first one. Second smtp will use users authentication from first smtp. All the domains/users mailboxes are exists on first smtp.

Comment: *cough* *cough*. You have 18 questions and have accepted answers on *none* of them. Go back and accept some answers and you'll find that more people are willing to spend time on answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not knew that how to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the hope that this user learned how to accept answers :) while I do not understand the question, pieces of it I might. If you want to configure an SMTP server to authenticate upstream, http://www.numlock.ch/news/it/postfix-outgoingoutbound-smtp-authentication-for-smtphispeedchcablecomch/ is an easy way. If you want several postfix servers to auth the same users, http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html is what I would do.